# Migrate from Merb to Rails3

Tags: merb, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best way to migrate from Merb to Rails3 ,i had a look at [merb-to-rails3](http://github.com/LunarLogicPolska/merb-to-rails3)
gem but i don't thing only with that gem i can completely migrate because the helper methods the gem provides are very less.